# getToolByName() vs. others

Tags: plone

What's the recommended method of accessing Plone persistent utilities and why?

- getToolByName(context, "portal_url")
- direct acquisition: context.portal_url
- ITools interface

etc.

Comment: And the last plone.api methods -  http://readthedocs.org/docs/ploneapi/en/latest/utilities.html#get-tool

Comment: I still consider plone.api a little experimetanl and thus not recommended... also I'd like know insight behind the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the answer is in the code of `getToolByName` itself ( http://svn.zope.org/Products.CMFCore/trunk/Products/CMFCore/utils.py?view=markup ). That method does this:

- as a first attempt it tries  to get the desired tool by looking up for the interface with `getUtility` and including it in a context (that seems a good thing to me)
- as a fallback it tries to directly acquire the tool from the source context

So the only method "to rule them all" seems to be: `getToolByName`
But, as @keul said, there's also the caching involved, and looking here ( http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/context.html#itools-interface ) it is clear that using the ITools interface, when it doesn't fail due to tools that don't yet implement that interface, it's faster.

For the reasons above, in the end I'd suggest:

1. ITools (faster)
2. getToolByName (safer)

(as the direct acquisition is already tried by the getToolByName, if it fails, you won't have more fortune)

Comment: because `getToolByName` is a method in the CMFCore package whilst `ITool` is an interface in `plone.app.layout`. As its domain name points out, p.a.layout it's an higher level package and it is Plone specific.

Answer (score 2):

The use of ITools utilities must be the best method, as they are cached. However this sometimes gave me problems (related to portal_membership tool, but I don't remember details) so in that rare cases I switch to getToolByName.
The last one is the direct acquisition.